# Exponential equation problems

Tags: logarithms

How should I solve the following equation:

$2_{}^{2x}-2{}^{2x+1}=3$

Comment: No solution is the real domain but solutions in the complex domain.

Answer (score 1):

I think we  have $-2^{2x}=3$, which is impossible in real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

but $$2^{2x}-2^{2x+1}=2^{2x}-2\cdot 2^{2x}=-2^{2x}<0$$ therefore no Solutions.